# Postman override response type

Tags: postman

Postman always defaults to "Auto" response type.  I'm working with an API that always returns `Content-Type:text/plain` even though it should be JSON.  Is there some way to force Postman to always display responses as pretty-printed JSON for a whole collection?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually Postman auto detects the response format using Content type header, specified in header  for every API request.

You can also specify to display auto select JSON in

```
 Settings -> General -> Language Detection to JSON
```

Comment: Great answer, although I think Postman would be better off having this setting per folder/request etc. Not all APIs have trouble returning the correct headers.

Answer (score 0):

This option is now found under

```
Settings -> General -> Response format detection
```

[image]